# Function MFP with LM in R howto

Tags: r, stata, glm, lm

I'm trying to use  the MFP function in R similarly to how I use the equivalent command in Stata. Normally when running an linear regression in Stata I use the command `mfp` before the command `regress` and Stata gives the 'best' transformations of covariates in the regression model. E.g. in Stata I use the command

```
mfp: regress variable1 variable2
```

There seems to be a function `mfp` in the library (`mfp`) in R which I would like to use.

e.g. in R:

```
summary(mfp(variable1 ~ fp(variable2)))
```

This gives me the results of an regression but R forces it somehow into a GLM model. The disadvantage of this is that I'm not getting an overall R-squared in comparison with a Linear Model (LM).

Does anybody know how to do an LM with the function MFP in R?

Comment: I don't know any specifics here about the R implemenation, but offer a  general comment: the broad attitude should be that R may well have its own very different ways of doing things. It no more promises to behave like other software than the converse is true. I am a Stata user, so not partisan here, just totally sympathetic to the possibility of quite different styles. All that said, this looks like a question of needing to study the documentation more carefully and not a programming problem strict sense.

Answer (score 2):

From the help function of mfp, it follows (using your example code):

```
model1 <- mfp(variable1 ~ fp(variable2), family=gaussian, data=...)
summary(model1)
```

You can calculate R-square by using the following code:

```
cor(model1$Y, model1$fitted.values)^2
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know regression in R, but this question can be answered from first principles in any statistics package. R-square is the square of the Pearson correlation between the observed and predicted responses in a multiple linear regression that includes an intercept. (e.g. Draper and Smith, 1966, p. 62). So 1) Add the predicted values from the R regression to the data set; 2) compute the Pearson correlation **r** between the responses & predicted values; 3) Square **r**.

References: 
NR Draper and H Smith (1966) Applied Regression Analysis, Wiley, NY.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_correlation